# base64 generated by osx shell can't be decoded from Java

Tags: java, macos, base64

I'm experiencing a weird behavior using base 64 encoding.

From a shell in OSX I do:

```
$ echo "hello world" | base64 -out my-file
$ cat my-file 
aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK
```

Then running the following Kotlin/Java code:

```kotlin
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.util.Base64

fun main() {
    val content = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("./my-file"))
    
    println("content=> ${String(content)}")
    
    val decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content)

    println("==> $decode")

}
```

But then I have the following exception:

```
content=> aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:791)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:567)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:8)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

EDIT:
changing the way the base64 is decoded with another class it is working:

```kotlin
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

fun main() {
    val content = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("./my-file"))

    val decode = org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(content)

    println("==> ${String(decode)}")

}
```

prints:
`==> hello world`

Comment: Did you check the value of `content`? Does it match your file's content? Also, do you realize `decode()` returns a byte array, i.e. `decode` will have type `byte[]`?

Comment: yep, content is right, and the `decode` method wants a `byte[]` :(

Comment: Therr is also decode(String).

Comment: Digging a little bit it seems that the file generated by the `base64` command has a new line at the end of the file